# Probably wrong brackets color in LESS with dreamweaver CC

Tags: css, ide, less, dreamweaver

When I complile a .less file with Dreamweaver CC I notice that maybe the brackets colors are wrong, but the code is prefectly fine and it works perfectly. Please, look at this screenshot:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you can solve it. It appears like DCC uses some conventional CSS parser for highlighting and therefore it supports Less syntax *very* loosly.

Comment: Seems like this is a known problem atleast with Dreamweaver CS5.5. Check if anything mentioned in [this thread](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5159905) helps you. Even this link I think has only a work-around and not a proper solution. The screenshot in the comment by Markus bei Plutonika seems to be indicating the same problem.

Comment: So, probably this problem will be solved in the next versions of DW. But for now, in your opinion which is the best web design and development application?

Comment: @Elle: I am not a developer mate, my line of work is totally different so I am not really aware which is the best. For my simple requirements I just use Notepad++.